# Clearcase and hudson - Unix master and windows slave

Tags: windows, unix, clearcase, master-slave

I work for a very large company which blindly follows UCM. Clercase is managed by UCM team.Everything happens by rule book. Clearcase clients on unix environment is rarity and we had lot of problems getting clearcase client installed on a unix box. But finally we got there. I use the unix as my master. My master has a few projects  and the ucm stream is defined for the UCM plugin view creation parameters as follows.

```
some_dev_shared_stream@/astream
```

load rules as following

```
vobs/myvob/component/
```

---

view gets created and works fine on unix, managed to setup a slave this morning and the slave is a windows box.

On build on the slave I get a UCM plugin error could not attach the view to the stream.

I took the make view command out, and changed  the "/" in  some_dev_shared_stream@/astream to "\" and ran the command from windows cmd mode and view was created.

My development workstation on windows box - the views do not have vobs in front of them, so I am kind of sure that also is going to be a problem.

has anybody come across the above?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, load rules (for snapshot views) start with a **Vob tag**:

- On Unix: `/vobs/aVobTag`
- on Windows: `/aVobTag` (on `\aVobTag`: doesn't matter)

Does your Windows UCM view follows that kind of load rule?

Comment: Apologies I did not put that question accross rightly. On my master my UCM configurations are stream selector -- Dev_Shared_xyz_Proj@/vobs/xxx_yy_pvob,load rules /vobs/xx_vob/,do not use update but recreate views every time.
it all works fine on the master but when I created a dumb slave on windows and ran the build on the node
the build failed as it could not understand the stream and gave an error could not attach the view to the stream.

Comment: following is the mkview command from hudson logs cleartool mkview -snapshot -stream Dev_Shared_xyz_Proj@/vobs/xxx_yy_pvob -tag cibuild_view2 -vws /export/home/ci/rational/cc_view_store/cibuild_view2.vws cibuild_view2.on windows we don’t have /vobs/ in the stream identifier.Also the view storage is different to /export/home/ci/rational/cc_view_store/Now my question is - do I need to change my configuration (always create the view), and use update, create a view manually on the slave and force hudson to use that view?Is there a way a slave can have its own configuration?

Comment: @jojoseph: why can't you have a similr Hudson config on Windows (as in "`cleartool mkview -snapshot -stream Dev_Shared_xyz_Proj@\xxx_yy_pvob -tag cibuild_view2 -vws c:\path\to\cc_view_store/cibuild_view2.vws cibuild_view2`"? I did explain in my answer that the vob tags in Windows don't have `/vobs` prefix. In other word, that would be a 'yes' to your question.